# How can I have multiple hyperlinks in the same column using JS render function?

Tags: hyperlink, shiny, datatables

I have a shiny app that displays a datatable (using DTedit R pckg) and I would like to:

1) **Insert all the hyperlinks in the same cell**, separated by a new line

2) **Open the hyperlinks in a different tab**.

For point 2, I have tried different versions of ' target="_blank" but it does not work. My guess is that I am doing something wrong with the quotes.

```
#E.g.: 
<a href=' + data + ' target='_blank'>' + 'PanelApp' + '</a>' ;}"
```

I have tried with double quotes too (target="_blank") but is not recognising them (I have zero experience in JS)

This is an example of the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
#devtools::install_github('jbryer/DTedit')
library(DTedit)

ui = fluidPage(
  h3("How can I have all the links in one column separated by <br> ?"),
  mainPanel(
    shiny::uiOutput("mytable")
  )
)

server = function(input, output){

  #dataframe
  mydata <- data.frame(Gene = c("GBE1", "KMT2D"),
                       Metric = c(10, 20))

  ## Add hyperlinks
  mydata$Decipher <- paste0("https://decipher.sanger.ac.uk/gene/", mydata$Gene, "#overview/protein-info")
  mydata$PanelApp <- paste0("https://panelapp.genomicsengland.co.uk/panels/entities/", mydata$Gene)

  #render table
  DTedit::dtedit(input, output,
                 name = 'mytable',
                 thedata = mydata,
                 datatable.options = list(
                   columnDefs = list(
                     list(targets= 2, 
                          render = JS("function(data){return '<a href=' + data + '>' + 'PanelApp' + '</a>' ;}")),
                     list(targets= 3, 
                          render = JS("function(data){return '<a href=' + data + '>' + 'Decipher' + '</a>' ;}"))
                     )
                   )
                 )
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(height = 1080))
```

Can anyone shed some light here?

THANK YOU!!

Comment: I would try `"function(data){return '<a href=\"' + data + '\" target=\"_blank\">' + 'PanelApp' + '</a>' ;}"`.

Comment: Thank you so much @StéphaneLaurent, that worked! For future references, basically, I had to manually escape the double quotes :). Any idea how can I create a column that contains all the hyperlinks (as oppose to one column per hyperlink)?  - THANKS!